# Create new column based on presence in previous index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

I have the following (exploded) dataframe:

[image]

I want to create a new column that indicates if a Date (column Date) is present in the previous index and/or the next index. This new column will have a value of:

- 0: not present in either of previous and next index
- 1: present in either previous or next index
- 2: present in both previous and next index

So for example for index 303:

Date 1991: new column value = 0 (as 1991 not present in index 302 and 304)

Date 1996: new column value = 1 (as 1996 present in index 302 but not in index 304)

Date 2010: new column value = 2 (as 2010 present in index 302 and 304)

Anyone knows how this can easily solved in a pandaic way?

Regards,

Dante

Comment: It is simple, but please share a data sample instead of an image so we don't have to regenerate sample data. See 
[Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Since no code was given I reproduced your dataframe in a simplified way.

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame(
    {"date": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a"]}, index=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
test.index.name = "index"

lists_df = test.groupby("index")["date"].agg(set)

res = (
    ((1- (test.date.agg(set) - lists_df.shift(1)[test.index]).fillna(True).astype(bool))
    +(1- (test.date.agg(set) - lists_df.shift(-1)[test.index]).fillna(True).astype(bool)))
)
print("original df\n", test)
print("resulting calculation\n", res)
```

prints out following result:

```
original df
       date
index     
1        a
1        b
1        c
2        a
2        a
2        a
3        b
3        b
3        a
resulting calculation
 index
1    1
1    0
1    0
2    2
2    2
2    2
3    0
3    0
3    1
Name: date, dtype: int64
```